# Mapping a javascript array of object to modify a string attribute

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects as such

```
{ 
"attr1": 123,
"attr2": "a.end", 
},
{
"attr1": 123,
"attr2": "b.start", 
}
```

I'm trying to remove the first part of the attr2 string up to and including the '.'

I've tried using

```
 arr.map ((item:any) => item.attr2 = item.attr2.split('.').pop())
```

but I'm getting the following arrow in my editor

```
Arrow function should not return assignment.eslintno-return-assign
```

My goal is to have arr looking like that

```
{ 
    "attr1": 123,
    "attr2": "end", 
},
{
    "attr1": 123,
    "attr2": "start", 
}
```

Comment: use `.forEach`. The `.map()` method is meant for building a whole new array. And the warning is that you're trying to use the return value of the assignment as the items for the new array, which looks to the linter like a mistake.

Comment: that's just a linting error... not an actual problem with your code. it should still run, to get rid of it just wrap the assignment in braces `=> {item.attr2 = item.attr2.split('.').pop()}`

Comment: @Klaycon: Why hinder the error instead of using the proper iteration method?

Comment: @slappy plugging `forEach` in where `map` is won't fix that linting error unless the braces are also added. The rule is to not return assignments, has nothing to do with map vs forEach.

Comment: You should not use `map` unless you use the return value of the `map` operation.

Comment: @Klaycon So the linter doesn't  catch that `.forEach()` ignores the return value of the callback? That's too bad. Seems like it should,

Comment: @slappy correct, the linter doesn't consider the context, only whether the arrow function is directly returning an assignment, according to that rule - you can quickly try it over at https://eslint.org/demo (just be sure to set the rules configuration, ECMA version = 2019 and check on `no-return-assign`)

Comment: @Klaycon: Cool Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still using map with only a few tweaks.

```
array.map(x => ({...x, attr2: x.attr2.split('.').pop()} ));
```

Answer (score 2):

The lint error says `no-return-assign` which means [Assignment in return Statement is disallowed](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign). The below will make the linter happy.

**Note:** Doing this will not affect the original array.`result` will be a new array with attr2 as expected.

```
let result = arr.map(item =>({...item, attr2:item.attr2.split('.').pop()}))
```

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "attr1": 123,
    "attr2": "a.end", 
  },
  {
    "attr1": 123,
    "attr2": "b.start", 
  }
];
console.log(arr.map(item =>({...item, attr2:item.attr2.split('.').pop()})))
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, the only issue is the linting error, not what everyone else is trying to fix - +1

Comment: @Klaycon: Sort of. Since the OP is trying to mutate the original objects, this isn't really equivalent. It can be a problem if there are other references to the objects or the array itself.

Comment: @slappy bah, you're right actually. It was just the only answer that provided a source and explained that the asker need only make the linter happy. I guess I'll throw in mine too

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to other answers, you can use RegExp

```js
const ret = [{
    attr1: 123,
    attr2: 'a.end',
  },
  {
    attr1: 23,
    attr2: 'b.start',
  }
].map(({
  attr2,
  ...otherArgs
}) => ({
  ...otherArgs,

  attr2: attr2.replace(/^.*\./g, ''),
}));

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works fine, if slightly inefficient due to using [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) where you should be using [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The error you shared is merely a linting error - it doesn't mean the code doesn't work, but you should fix it anyway to match the code style of your project.

The rule being broken is [`no-return-assign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign). An arrow function with no braces implicitly returns whatever the result of the expression is, so your arrow function currently is returning that assignment even though you don't really care that it does so. To satisfy the linter you can simply wrap the assignment in braces, as below.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "attr1": 123,
    "attr2": "a.end", 
  },
  {
    "attr1": 123,
    "attr2": "b.start", 
  }
];
arr.map((item) => {item.attr2 = item.attr2.split('.').pop()});
```

Here's also an [eslint demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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) with the rule enabled to show that it no longer errors.

As pointed out in comments, if you have the eslint rule `array-callback-return` that one might get thrown by this fix. In that case you may simply use `arr.forEach` instead of `arr.map` to satisfy it.

Comment: Would it not give the lint errors ``array-callback-return`` and ``no-param-reassign``

Comment: @RaviKukreja maybe, I don't know the asker's full eslint config. it wouldn't give `no-param-reassign` as the parameter isn't being reassigned, only a property of it.

Answer (score 1):

try this
arr.map ((item) => {return item.attr2 = item.attr2.split('.').pop()})

maybe your linter didn't accept the way you wrote it

Answer (score 0):

You could use `forEach`

```js
arr=[{ "attr1": 123, "attr2": "a.end", }, { "attr1": 123, "attr2": "b.start", }]
arr.forEach(o=>{var n=o.attr2.split(".")[1];o["attr2"]=n})
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Map is an array high order function that returns a NEW array based on what you tell it to do!

item.attr2 = item.attr2.split('.').pop()

this right here is an assignment you cant set this to a new array in an arrow function *cuz some linters will throw an error*

instead you will create a new array that has the new changes that you have set

so you either have to create a new array with the changes u made (if u want to use map) or use forEach and loop through it

Comment: `this right here is an assignment you cant set this to a new array` - actually you can, and the asker's code works fine, it's only a linting error

Comment: in his case he cant and his code is not working fine he wants to edit the array that has 2 objects but his code will return an new array like this ["end", "start"]
he wants to change the first array directly

Comment: He is not storing the result of the `map`, just using it as a shorter way to run some operation on every element of the array. In this case, the `map` callback mutates each element - it should be a forEach, but that doesn't matter, his code still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes works for me. I think your linter causes the error.
But you can use `forEach`, your object will be update thanks of ref pointer.
This will be more performing, because when you use `map` method, it generate a new array. Thanks of `forEach` you will update your exist array object.

Js:

```
const arr  = [{ 
"attr1": 123,
"attr2": "a.end", 
},
{
"attr1": 123,
"attr2": "b.start", 
}] 
arr.forEach(item=>{
  item.attr2 = item.attr2.split('.').pop()
 });
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new array and change the wanted property.

```js
let array = [{ attr1: 123, attr2: "a.end" }, { attr1: 123, attr2: "b.start" }];

array = array.map(({ attr2, ...o }) => ({ ...o, attr2: attr2.split('.').pop() }));

console.log(array);
```